# Provide class metadata to the generic in swift (Codable)

Tags: swift

I have a method that works on `Codable`s and does, among other things, this:

```
func doWhatever<T>() -> T? where T: Codable {
   var myName = String(describing: T.self)
   return nil // or whatever
}
```

Then i can get `myName` as the class name at run time to get the right data to create an instance of `T`.

Now some of my `Codable` need to provide a `custom` name for this.

So while i could edit ALL of my codables (a few hundred models) to conform to `some protocol` that provides name, i **really** want to avoid doing it.

Since there are no custom attributes in Swift, i concocted this;

```
protocol MetadataProvidingCodable {
    static func customName() -> String
}
```

Then in my generic i can check whether the `T` conforms to it:

```
func doWhatever<T>() -> T? where T: Codable {
   var myName = String(describing: T.self)
   if T.self is MetadataProvidingCodable.Type {
      myName = ... // Get customName() from T without an instance???
   }

   return nil // or whatever
}
```

But my problem is that i need to be able to call my static func on the `T` type without having an instance of `T`. Is that possible?

Comment: Best thing I can think to do is check all the cases directly to see if they're one of the types you know has metadata. How many of them have the metadata you need to read?

Comment: @KyleBurns the issue is this solution will not be maintainable. There are a bunch of these generic methods and any time a developer adds the type with custom metadata he would need to go to some OTHER classes to provide pieces of this custom metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type cast the `T.self` as `MetadataProvidingCodable.Type` like that:

```
func doWhatever<T>() -> T? where T: Codable {
    var myName = String(describing: T.self)
    if let type = T.self as? MetadataProvidingCodable.Type {
        myName = type.customName()
    }

    return nil // or whatever
}
```

**Edit**: If you can somehow move the common logic to a separate function, you can override the `doWhatever()` function with another one that return a type that conforms to both `Codable` and `MetadataProvidingCodable`.

Then the compiler will figure out what function will call based on the return type:

```
func doWhatever<T>() -> T? where T: Codable {
    print("doWhatever: Codable")
    var myName = String(describing: T.self)
    return nil
}

func doWhatever<T>() -> T? where T: Codable & MetadataProvidingCodable {
    print("doWhatever: Codable & MetadataProvidingCodable")
    var myName = T.customName()
    return nil
}

struct Example1: Codable {}
struct Example2: Codable, MetadataProvidingCodable {
    static func customName() -> String {
        return "Example2"
    }
}

let example1: Example1? = doWhatever()
let example2: Example2? = doWhatever()

// prints
// doWhatever: Codable
// doWhatever: Codable & MetadataProvidingCodable
```